# Hyperlinks inside object fields

Tags: ember.js

I have an object inside my `Ember` app, with a description field. This description field may contain hyperlinks, like this

```
My fancy text <a href='http://other.site.com' target='_blank'>My link</a> My fancy text continues...
```

However, when i output it normally, like `{{ description }}` my hyperlinks are displayed as a plain text. Why is this happening and how can i fix this?

Comment: Use triple mustaches if you must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars escapes any HTML within output by default. For unescaped text in markup use *triple-stashes*:

```
{{{ description }}}
```

There's an alternative when one controls the property: *Handlebars.SafeString*. SafeStrings are assumed to be safe and are not escaped either. From [the documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function(text, url) {
  text = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(text);
  url  = Handlebars.Utils.escapeExpression(url);

  var result = '<a href="' + url + '">' + text + '</a>';

  return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
});
```

**Note** - please be careful with this. There are security concerns with rendering unescaped text that has come from user input; an attacker could inject a malicious script into the description and hijack your page, for example.

Comment: Turns out, i needed a lot more than this. This field was languaged, so i had to put it through helper that chose correct language suffix for it, and also truncate it if necessary. And i solved my problem with `return new Handlebars.SafeString()`. Thanks for your help with escaping anyways.

Comment: @TwiStar Yeah, SafeString prevents escaping too; I'll add that to the answer for completeness. Glad you got it sorted :)